# Cannot read JNDI .bindings file inside openjdk:8-jdk-alpine based docker container

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, ibm-mq, jndi

I'm trying to use fxcontext.jar to get IBM MQ connection factory from JNDI.
My environment properties are:

```
    environment.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContextFactory");
    environment.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "file:///");
    ...
```

Then JNDI Object Factory Bean creation code like this:

```
private JndiObjectFactoryBean createJndiObjectFactoryBean(String connectionFactoryJndi) {
    JndiObjectFactoryBean jndiObjectFactoryBean = new JndiObjectFactoryBean();
    jndiObjectFactoryBean.setCache(true);
    jndiObjectFactoryBean.setProxyInterface(QueueConnectionFactory.class);
    jndiObjectFactoryBean.setLookupOnStartup(false);
    jndiObjectFactoryBean.setJndiName(connectionFactoryJndi);
    return jndiObjectFactoryBean;
}

...

JndiObjectFactoryBean jndiObjectFactoryBean = createJndiObjectFactoryBean(connectionFactoryName);
jndiObjectFactoryBean.setJndiEnvironment(environment);

...

applicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().initializeBean(jndiObjectFactoryBean, "QM1Bean");

QueueConnectionFactory connectionFactory = (QueueConnectionFactory) jndiObjectFactoryBean.getObject();
```

I have configured .bindings file using JMSAdmin from IBM MQ java\bin directory and put it into root directories:

- on my host OS (path "d:\.bindings", OS Windows);
- on my docker-image based on openjdk:8-jdk-alpine (path "/.bindings", OS Linux).

This code successfully works on my host system, so the message exchange between Spring Boot application and IBM MQ is ok.
But when I start it inside my docker-container there is a problem with JNDI Lookup. The last log entry is:

```
2021-08-06 10:36:29.119 DEBUG 1 --- [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1] org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate    : Looking up JNDI object with name [QCF]
```

... and nothing happens at all: no exceptions, no errors, no message exchange.

What I'm doing wrong?
I had to rebuild my solution using "ancient" mqcontext.jar and it works fine in both cases. But now I have "a sports interest" to understand the problem with fscontext.jar usage inside docker-container.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you configure the JNDI in your docker environment. Because QCF Lookup is checked JNDI is not available in this environment. So you can add in docker for JNDI.

Comment: Do you have fscontext.jar and providerutil.jar?

Comment: @Sathiyaraj, are you speaking about .bindings file in root directory? Yes, I copied .bindings into containers / (root) and, as you can see, PROVIDER_URL was set "file:///" (works on Windows and on Linux).

Comment: @JoshMc, I have fscontext.jar (for context factory com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContextFactory), but no providerutil.jar. Is it mandatory and for what? On host OS it works without providerutil.jar.

Comment: As far as I know you must have those 2 along with jms.jar and com.ibm.mq.allclient.jar.  I've never tried without providerutil.jar when bindings files are involved.